# Android Bluetooth - Hide failure toast notifications

Tags: android, bluetooth, toast

When attempting to pair with a Bluetooth device (programatically), in the case where, for example a pin code is incorrect, Android will display a toast notification to the user.

I'd prefer to handle this fully in code without the default system toasts.

Is it possible to hide these system notifications ?

Comment: I'm in the same situation and so far, I've found none.  Perhaps a cruise through the Android Bluetooth code will provide a revelation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that these toast msgs are coming out of BluetoothEventManager.java in the platform Bluetooth settings package and are triggered based on the reason for the pairing failure, identified by an EXTRA_REASON in the Intent associated with the BOND_NONE state transition.  Only specific reasons cause a toast msg to be displayed.  If you can manipulate the reason code in that Intent, you'll suppress the toast.

So far, I haven't been successful in doing that though.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comments. It is a rather frustrating issue. I'm not currently still looking at this and never found a solution but if I do get the chance to return to it and solve it, I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

As a more heavy-handed alternative, if you can modify and build your Android platform source, you can gut the .showError() method in

```
./packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/Utils.java
```

and prevent the toast messages as well.